# Is "for the purpose that" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions, coordination

I have googled and rarely found the example of usage.  Instead I found "for the purpose of" is more common. My English teacher, who is not English-native speaker, showed me one but I rather disagree with her. 
For example: The spy dyed his hair (,since/,so/;hence,/for the purpose that) he wouldn't be recognized. 
Her answer is "for the purpose that". I thought  "so" or "hence" is more suitable.

Comment: "Grammatically correct" isn't a useful concept here. The cited "answer" is completely ***non-idiomatic***. Note that the word ***that*** is entirely optional after ***so*** in such contexts. Also note that ***so** [that]* is the only credible answer among those possibilities you've set out (one valid alternative is ***in order that***, but this wouldn't be common). Finally, ***hence*** has a slightly different meaning, which *doesn't* suit your context.

Comment: All are pretty bad: The spy died his hare so he wouldn't be recognized. There is no need for heavy circumlocutions. You are right, "so" is best. "hence" means therefore.

Answer (score 1):

For example: The spy dyed his hair (,since/,so/;hence,/for the purpose that) he wouldn't be recognized. [buzzer]

Corrected:

For example: The spy dyed his hair **so** he wouldn't be recognized. 
OR
For example: The spy dyed his hair for the purpose of not being recognized.

Comment: Also, "in order not to be recognized", "so as not to be recognized", "with the intent of avoiding recognition"... none of which is as good as "so" :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak The more the merrier. :)

Answer (score -1):

So, hence, and for the purpose that are all correct. It depends on your context and where you are speaking.

The "purpose of" something is the reason that it exists, its intended function. This is an abstraction, typically.

The "purpose for" something is an actual use. This is a concrete example.

The "purpose that" something is used when there are multiple purposes and this is calling out one in particular.

Examples:

The spy dyed his hair for the purpose of blending in to his surroundings.

The purpose for the spy dying his hair was to blend in to his surroundings.

The spy dyed his hair for the purpose that he was meant to deceive the enemy.

These can interchange a bit with subtle meaning shifts.